Track details of all developer on Jira
I have a Jira Board with columns New, On Hold, In Progress, In Review,  Ready for Test, Staged, Done. There are developers and testers in the group along with a Team Lead who checks Merge all the PRs.
At the time when a jira ticket is in New, On Hold or In Progress the ticket is assigned to the developer and the developer adds there name as Developer in ticket details like this
Ticket Details.
When this ticket is moved  to In Review, Ready for Test, Staged or Done the Assigned User is changed. For Ready for Test the ticket is assigned to the Tester and in rest of the columns the ticket is assigned to Team Lead.
I want to track the progress of Developers and Testers like how many tickets were completed by the Developer in the sprint and how much time the tester took to test that ticket. As in the done column all the tickets are assigned to Team Lead.
With the help of filters I want to track these progress. I tried this jql query to track the progress of an individual developer.
"developer 1 [people]" = currentUser()
ORDER BY status ASC, created DESC

I would like to track details of all developer and also testers. And I'm pretty sure I could do that directly with jql queries. Any ideas or recommendations ?
Thanks
